# Slow login, logout and su on Centos

Tags: ssh, rsyslogd

It's been weeks that ssh login, logout and using su to other users on a CentOS 6.8 server been very slow, it takes around 20 seconds to 45 seconds for the login or logout or su to take effect. All my other servers are working fine, just three of my servers with same usage been affected by this problem.

When I restart my rsyslog service everything is fine for a few seconds, then again the login logout and su get slow.

any ideas whats causing this slowness and how can I fix it.

Comment: Check your DNS configuration; that smells like a lookup timeout.

Comment: then why does it get fixed after I restart rsyslog service ?